# what is the proper place to use setInterval function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an component.

- *Functionality:* calling list of host and showing their status that is up or down.

Within componentDidmount(), i am using setInerval() function, that causes whole component re-render when ever one or only two status are changing.

- *Scenario:* I have 12 host in the list, I am calling each and updating their status.
- *Case-1:* In first interval 10 host status is up and rest 2 are down. for next call 
  again 10 host status is up and rest 2 are down, but the whole component is being rendered. that should not be.
- *What I tried:*

```js
class _Grid extends Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        if(this.props.card === nextProps.card){
            return false;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { card, classes } = this.props;
        const up = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA/Z";
        const down = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoCC";

        return (
            <Grid item key={card.app} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <CardMedia
                        image={card.status == 'up' ? up : down}
                        className={classes.cardMedia}
                        title="Image title"
                    />
                    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2">
                            {card.appName}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Grid>);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the setInterval used? I can't see it in given snippet. Please update your question

Comment: @ShubhamGupta _Within componentDidmount(), i am using setInerval() function_.. :)

Comment: @Rahul Raj Sonu I think you should add some code before I can understand/help you

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are doing a `===` comparison on `props` and `nextProps` in `shouldComponentUpdate` method. In javascript comparing two objects with strict equality comparison returns true only if both variables refer to the same object. In your example I don't see the logic that updates the props value, but I assume that the props is re-created in the setInterval, which means that a new object is created every time. For methods of deep-comparing the objects by value please refer to other stackoverflow answers: